# If there are two possible reactions, will the one with a more negative Gibbs Free Energy be favored?

Tags: organic-chemistry, physical-chemistry

I was thinking of the reaction between methanol (CH3OH) and sodium amide (NaNH2) and wondering if I could get methylamine (CH3NH2) from it. One reaction forms methylamine and sodium hydroxide, while the other produces sodium methoxide and ammonia. When calculating the Gibbs Free Energy for both reaction at STP, the Gibbs Free Energy for the methylamine and sodium hydroxide reaction is about x1.5 more negative compared to the other reaction. However, many websites say that the sodium methoxide reaction is the one that happens. Is this true? If so, why?

Comment: Favoured thermodynamically or kinetically?

Comment: Thermodynamically. I don't know the kinetics of it, but from what I can conclude they should be about the same.

Comment: Hmm, I would say the acidobasic reaction would be much faster than substitution.

Comment: I understand that substitution reactions are generally slower than acid-base reactions, but is there a way to make it more favorable so that the reaction will proceed?